# Should simple collaborater/dependencies be mocked

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

When to mock and when to not.

If i were to be writing a unit test for MyObject->doSomething() in the following example:

```
class Factory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function create($name) {
        return new MyOtherObject($name); 
    }
}

class MyOtherObject
{
    public function doSomethingElse() {
        // Do something here
    }
}

class MyObject implements MyObjectInterface
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory) {
        $this->factory = $factory;        
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        $myOtherObject = $this->factory->create($name);
        return 100 + $myOtherObject->doSomething();
    }
}
```

Would $factory need to be mocked, and in turn I would then need a nested mock for MyOtherObject also?

The alternative would be to create concrete classes and pass them in my tests?

Answer (score 1):

The factory dependency would need to be mocked in this case because there seems to be nothing else that can be tested without mocking the factory first. But is the intent of the test case to test that the factory's `create` method is called, or perhaps some other part of `doSomething`'s contract?

If you wanted to test what happens on the `return` statement you could extract the creation of `myOtherObject` into a method

```
public function createOtherObject($name)
{
    return $this->factory->create($name);
}
```

and now you can test the behavior of `doSomething` without having to mock the factory (you can simply stub or override `createOtherObject`, and if you want to test the factory call that would be a different test, on `createOtherObject`).

Even in this simple scenario such a refactoring would allow you to mock the factory and its created object on a need basis instead of forcing both to be mocked even if you just want to test the `return` behavior.

That possibility aside, assuming you need to test everything anyway then yes, the factory and its creation would need to be mocked (or stubbed; by "create concrete classes" you probably mean stubs).